# What are the origins of Shia and Sunni division?

Tags: sunni, history, shiism, shia-sunni, politics

Can anyone tell me about the origins of Shia and Sunni division? Why were two different groups of Muslims created?

Allah didn't send us to live divided. No verse of Quran or Hadith suggest that as far as I know. Both of the groups are driven by great scholars. They know Quran and Hadith very well still they are leading to something that Allah does not like?

Is there any political involvement?

Comment: It looks like it was because of some political events in that era. But I have a hard time understanding why they are still being divided.

Comment: The correct question when speaking about the origins should be "Shia / Non-Shia" division; "Shia / Sunni" is highly misleading and anachronistic.

Comment: To me it makes sense. I don't understand why it doesn't for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The religion, Islam, born from the Book, Qur'an, but sects, Shi'a, Sunni and others are born from "history" of Islam. There is no debate on the Book, Qur'an, but there is a lot of debate on "history". If you wipe out whole history the religion, Islam, will stand through Qur'an but all sects will be wiped out as well. A large part history of world is fabricate but who does care? But in this case it is related to a "belief" and made problems.
The main question is: What if we didn't know about the history?

As Qur'an says what is brought by the Messenger is enough for human [An-Nisa/165](http://quran.com/4/165):

> رُسُلًا مُبَشِّرِينَ وَمُنْذِرِينَ لِئَلَّا يَكُونَ لِلنَّاسِ عَلَى
>   اللَّهِ حُجَّةٌ بَعْدَ الرُّسُلِ وَكَانَ اللَّهُ عَزِيزًا حَكِيمًا
>   ﴿النساء: ١٦٥﴾
>
> Messengers bearing good tidings, and warning, so that mankind might
>   have no argument against Allah, after the Messengers; Allah is
>   All-mighty, All-wise.

Comment: which verse is it. please mention it in your answer

Comment: This answer is quite a candid call to ignorance! "Forget about history"! as if Quran itself is not part of history! Also, the differences among Shiite and Sunni do not only stem from the aftermath of Prophet's death but also how they interpret the Quran and Sunna!

Comment: @infatuated History is the main source of debate. Even difference in interpretation of Qur'an and Sunna arises from history.

Comment: @Bhribayli, Yes, so let's just throw all history books including the Quran into fire and rid the world of evil!

Comment: @infatuated Qur'an is NOT a history book. Every history is THEORY that can be narrated in different and even contradicting ways. But narration of Qur'an for any historical event is a FACT. By the way it is not destroyable. Even if you burn every and any Qur'an found in the world, it would be easy to reconstruct exactly the same book in any Muslim city.

Comment: @Bhribayli, my point was that Quran is also basically a historically record, albeit well established and preserved. So in essence there's no difference between Quran and other hadith/historical documents other than the fact the latter sources are not yet as widely agreed and established as the Quran. But that also doesn't mean we should abandon them as many of the content/documents can be verified with proper application of the historical method.

Comment: @infatuated There is no way to verify those documents. They are and will remain as source of debate and conflict between Muslims. While there is debate on the form that Holy Prophet performed Wudu and Salat (activities that were done 5 times a day in front of eyes of all Muslims every day), you won't be able to verify other historical records. You can not even compile a little booklet with hadiths that all Muslim agree upon. But no one dispute over originality of Qur'an.

Comment: This answer is a concealed Quranist argument, which is but a vulgar reductionist and indefensible view of the form: Had Allah printed and published Quran instead of a revelation and Prophet, it doesn't take away anything from Islam, actually improves it. They turn a blind eye to the very historicity of Quran. For one, it was compiled in history.

Comment: "There is no debate on the Book, Quran" -- What can I say except: Ignorance is bliss!

Comment: @Shoaib Here we are talking about history of Islam outside Quran. History of early rise of Islam is captured in Quran, the most trustworthy source, and we may achieve more through chronological reading of Ayahs. But you won't be able to extract sects out of that history. All sects rely on the history which starts when Wahy ceases.
>> "There is no debate on the Book, Quran" -- What can I say except: Ignorance is bliss! <<
Did sects burst out of the debate on the Quran? You may say: 'tis folly to be wise ;-)

Comment: @Shoaib Don't jump from an argument to another one. Current argument is not about authenticity of Quran but origin of sects. To clarify the issue, answer these two questions: 1. Does Quran accept sects in Islam? 2. Are current sects born from a debate on the Quran? And at last but not least I refer you to Quran and ask you, as a Muslim, to watch your words: Al-Isar/17 http://quran.com/17/53

Comment: @Shoaib Dear Shoaib, authenticity of Quran does not depend on history and a historical proof is not reliable on the subject. I also believe that here is not the correct place for the argument but let's leave the comments for those who are seeking for a clue.

Answer (score 8):

**Can anyone tell me about the Origin of Shia and Sunni?**

Shia Shiite Shi’ite Shii'te Shīʿah Shi’ite Shi’ites Shias all are the same word for شيعه which means follower [of someone]/ sect. In Shia/Sunni debates means "Shia of Ali". Shia is not limited to Shia of Ali S.A. and for example Shia of Muaviyeh existed in past but later only Shia of Ali S.A. remained in history.

The word Shia شيعه in used in 3 verses of Quran and this can be considered as Origin of this word. [one verse](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/961/why-does-shia-islam-differ-so-much-regarding-abu-bakr-omar-and-othman-compare) says Ibrahim S.A. was Shia of Noah S.A.

> وَإِنَّ مِن شِيعَتِهِ لَإِبْرَاهِيمَ
>
> [[37:83]][2]  And indeed, among his sect was Abraham,

Other verse says:

> ثُمَّ لَنَنزِعَنَّ مِن كُلِّ شِيعَةٍ أَيُّهُمْ أَشَدُّ عَلَى
>   الرَّحْمَـٰنِ عِتِيًّا
>
> [[19:69]][3]  Then We will surely extract from every sect those of
>   them who were worst against the Most Merciful in insolence.

And other verse is about Shia of Moses S.A:

> وَدَخَلَ الْمَدِينَةَ عَلَىٰ حِينِ غَفْلَةٍ مِّنْ أَهْلِهَا فَوَجَدَ
>   فِيهَا رَجُلَيْنِ يَقْتَتِلَانِ هَـٰذَا مِن شِيعَتِهِ وَهَـٰذَا مِنْ
>   عَدُوِّهِ ۖ فَاسْتَغَاثَهُ الَّذِي مِن شِيعَتِهِ عَلَى الَّذِي مِنْ
>   عَدُوِّهِ فَوَكَزَهُ مُوسَىٰ فَقَضَىٰ عَلَيْهِ ۖ قَالَ هَـٰذَا مِنْ
>   عَمَلِ الشَّيْطَانِ ۖ إِنَّهُ عَدُوٌّ مُّضِلٌّ مُّبِينٌ
>
> [[28:15]][4]  And he entered the city at a time of inattention by
>   its people and found therein two men fighting: one from his sect and
>   one from among his enemy. And the one from his sect called for help to
>   him against the one from his enemy, so Moses struck him and
>   [unintentionally] killed him. [Moses] said, "This is from the work of
>   Satan. Indeed, he is a manifest, misleading enemy."

Also there are another verse with the same root and similar word but not exactly Shia. This verse is usually used by Sunnis against Shia for trying to disprove them:

> إِنَّ الَّذِينَ فَرَّقُوا دِينَهُمْ وَكَانُوا شِيَعًا لَّسْتَ مِنْهُمْ
>   فِي شَيْءٍ ۚ إِنَّمَا أَمْرُهُمْ إِلَى اللَّـهِ ثُمَّ يُنَبِّئُهُم
>   بِمَا كَانُوا يَفْعَلُونَ
>
> [[6:159]][5]  Indeed, those who have divided their religion and
>   become sects - you, [O Muhammad], are not [associated] with them in
>   anything. Their affair is only [left] to Allah; then He will inform
>   them about what they used to do.

Also the word Sunni does not exist in Quran and this term was used later.

according to Shia Muslims this verse does not include to Shia of Ali S.A. because this verse prohibit MAKING SECT and not belonging to a sect like Ibrahim S.A. belonged to Noah S.A. sect. in fact Shia consider its religion exactly the original religion of prophet and not a created sect. and consider the group who disobeyed the will of God for appointing Ali S.A. as Caliph at Ghadir the group who separated the order of prophet and created a sect.

The reason is that according to Shia only God can select the Caliph and God selected his Caliph after prophet and he was Ali S.A. and Ali S.A. received divine knowledge of prophet to guide humans and prophet declared it in front of 120,000 Muslims at Ghadir at final Hajj of prophet and Abubakr and Umar and Uthman given Bayat (pledge of alliance) to Ali S.A. but when prophet died and Ali S.A. was at funeral of prophet they left the funeral and made a meeting at Saqifah Bani Saedeh and selected Abubakr as Caliph without any permission from God and prophet and cause misguide of all humanity.

the conflict of Shia and Sunni started by death of prophet when Ali S.A. and more than 100 of Sahaba did not given Bayat to Abubakr because they believed [Allah and prophet declared Ali S.A. as Caliph][6] after death of prophet and Ali S.A. and also believed the Caliphet of Abubakr was not legimate. Those Sahaba wondered for selection of Abubakr while Ali S.A. was at funeral of prophet. And this conflict continued until today.

**Why 2 different group of Muslims is created?**

because one group believe Caliph can be selected only by God and other group believed Caliph can be selected by people by shura (meeting of leaders of tribes) or by will of past Caliph (like selection of Umar) or by voting (like demand of most of people from Ali S.A. to accept Caliphate after Uthman was killed by a group made of All groups Muslims)

**Allah didn't send us to live divided.  No verse of Quran or Hadish suggest that as per my knowledge.**

I think Allah wanted this to test us in Ahl ul-Bayt. Quran says:

> ... Had Allah willed, He would have made you one nation [united in
>   religion], but [He intended] to test you in what He has given you; so
>   race to [all that is] good. To Allah is your return all together, and
>   He will [then] inform you concerning that over which you used to
>   differ. [5:48]

**Both the groups are driven by great scholars.**

Depends on what you define great scholar. According to Shia a scholar who ignore will of Allah and prophet in selecting Caliph is not a great scholar.

**They know Quran and Hadish very well**

InshaAllah this be true.

"Still why they are leading to something that Allah does not likes?"

It’s not leaded by scholars. It’s leaded by political Kings. Scholars are not free to decide about political aspects of Islam. According to Islam there is only one nation of Muslim (Ummah) and only one Caliph. But if a King accept his should deliver the power to real Caliph of Allah and this is not what a King likes. For example you say this fact about Mubarak and Ghazafi who were two King in Islamic countries.

**Is there any political (government) involvement also?**

This matter is 99.99% political.

According to Shia the current legitimate Caliph is [Imam Mahdi S.A.][7] who is alive and leading and supporting Muslims but for will of Allah is in hide. But exist among us and we see him but do not know him.

**Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) has two famous sayings about sects of Muslims:**

1)  The Judaism nation after Moses (PBUH) became 71 sect that 70 of them are in Hell and 1 in Heaven and Christianity nation after Jesus (PBUH) became 72 sect that 71 of them are in Hell and 1 in Heaven and Islam nation after prophet become 73 sect that 72 of them are in Hell and 1 in Heaven.

2)  Truth is with Ali and Ali is with Truth

**related question:**

[https://islam.stackexchange.com](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/961/why-does-shia-islam-differ-so-much-regarding-abu-bakr-omar-and-othman-compare)

Comment: 37:83 is about the sect of Ibrahim against kufr (pagans). We are discussing the sects born out of Islam, we are not considering whole Islam as a sect as in 37:83.

Comment: @AhmedHan according to Quran all prophets were Muslim. also this verse proves following a sect which is the pure and original religion of God is allowed. but making any other sect is forbidden according to Quran. what means "sect agaist Kufr"? where is "against Kufr" in this verse? sect is not about against anything. sect means fraction/follower and is for divisions in a religion. anyway rules about sect are the same in Quran and Ibrahim followed the rules of Islam also. if following sect is bad so why Ibrahim S.A. labeled sect of Noah S.A.? what is bad in Islam is MAKING SECT not following it

Comment: @AhmedHan you mean Ibrahim S.A. had any religion rather than Islam. Quran clearly says he was Muslim. did I ever considered whole Islam as a sect? this verse never means whole the nation of time of Ibrahim S.A. as one sect but it means at time of Ibrahim S.A. there different sects of religion but Noah S.A. was from sect of Ibrahim S.A. I only want to conclude from this verse that following a sect is not bad in Quran. but some claim any kind of talking about sect is totally prohibited in Islam which is a false claim by this verse of Quran.

Comment: "Abubakr and Umar and Uthman given Bayat (pledge of alliance) to Ali S.A." - is there hadith about that?

Comment: "Ali S.A. received divine knowledge of prophet to guide humans and prophet declared it in front of 120,000 Muslims at Ghadir" - i have looked at your link from the other question , about ghadir, and i see that muhammad said : "For whoever I am his Leader (mawla), 'Ali is his Leader (mawla)."

Comment: but mawla is not leader and not caliph, it is translated as "protector" here : http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=wly . the root w l y has mostly meaning to turn and to take as friend. but in http://www.tyndalearchive.com/tabs/lane/ppages/Lane-P786734.gif it is also "lord" and son of uncle, son of sister, freedman , as i understand, but it is quite strange, or it is modern arabic and different from old arabic, i assume.

Comment: @qdinar translators translate based on their sect or based on their relation with dictator kings who feel danger about leadership of anyone other than themselves. for example Abu Hanifa was sent to jail for saying something against the king. they are not free. also for being a protector of people it is needed to have political power. in fact all the meanings altogether is true. not only one and leaving other that is against benefit of kings.

Answer (score 4):

The main origin of Shia, is the basic belief in Hajjatul-Wada' حجه الوداع when the Prophet(s.a.) for the last time visited Mecca and many people accompanied him, on the way back near غدیرخم Ghadir pond, the Prophet(s.a.) ordered everyone to stay and sent for others in front to return and waited for those behind to come up and after some thousand people were gathered He ordered to make a platform like place with camel saddles and then he went up with Imam Ali (as) and took up his hand and told people that

> Whoever I am his Mola مولى from now on Ali is his Mola.

Then he told them to spread the word and tell everyone.

Here Shias believe that Prophet(s.a.) clearly appointed Ali(a.s.) as his successor.

[**This is the fundamental belief of Shia.**](http://www.al-islam.org/ghadir/incident.htm)

I also like to mention that Shias don't see themselves separated from Sunni brothers and that we always should be united. As we all live by the *La Ilaha Illallah* and the love toward his last Prophet.

Comment: your response could be considered as a brief impartial reponse, especially you declared " Shias don't see themselves separated from Sunni brothers and that we always should be united." / Well done mate.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I had the opportunity to take a look at some of the Sunni Tafseer books in which I found the followings interesting as an answer to this question. According to these quotes from the Sunni books Shi'ite existed at the time of the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- as well:

Abu Ja'far Muhammad ibn Jareer Tabary (the 4th Hijri century) has written in his book that the holy prophet --peace be upon him-- told imam Ali --peace be upon him-- that you and your followers (Shia) are the best of creatures:

> يقول تعالى ذكره: إن الذين آمنوا بالله و رسوله محمد، و عبدوا الله
>   مخلصين له الدين حنفاء، و أقاموا الصلاة، و آتوا الزكاة، و أطاعوا الله
>   فيما أمر و نهى. أُولئِكَ هُمْ خَيْرُ الْبَرِيَّةِ يقول: من فعل ذلك من
>   الناس فهم خير البرية. و قد: حدثنا ابن حميد، قال: ثنا عيسى بن فرقد، عن
>   أبي الجارود، عن محمد بن علي أُولئِكَ هُمْ خَيْرُ الْبَرِيَّةِ فقال
>   النبي صلى الله عليه و سلم:" أنت يا علي و شيعتك"
>
> ابو جعفر محمد بن جرير طبرى (قرن ۴)، جامع البيان في تفسير القرآن، ج30،
>   ص: 171

Jalaliddin Soyuti (the 10th Hijri century) has written in his book that the holy prophet --peace be upon him-- told imam Ali --peace be upon him-- that he (the best of creatures) is you and your followers (Shia), in the Day you are well pleased and well-pleasing unto Him, and our rendezvous will be at the pond ...!

> و أخرج ابن عدى عن ابن عباس قال لما نزلت إِنَّ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَ
>   عَمِلُوا الصَّالِحاتِ أُولئِكَ هُمْ خَيْرُ الْبَرِيَّةِ قال رسول الله
>   صلى الله عليه و سلم لعلي هو أنت و شيعتك يوم القيامة راضين مرضيين
>
> و أخرج ابن مردويه عن علي قال قال لي رسول الله صلى الله عليه و سلم ألم
>   تسمع قول الله إِنَّ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَ عَمِلُوا الصَّالِحاتِ
>   أُولئِكَ هُمْ خَيْرُ الْبَرِيَّةِ أنت و شيعتك و موعدي و موعدكم الحوض
>   إذا حيت الأمم للحساب تدعون غرا محجلين
>
> جلال الدین سیوطی (قرن ۱۰)، الدر المنثور في تفسير المأثور، ج6، ص: 379

Sayyed Mahmoud Alousy (the 13th Hijri century) has written in his book that the holy prophet --peace be upon him-- told Imam Ali --peace be upon him-- that they (the best of creatures) are you and your followers (Shia), and our rendezvous will be at the pond ...! And the Prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- said this at his death while his head was on the breast of Imam Ali --peace be upon him.

> فقد أخرج ابن مردويه عن علي كرم اللّه تعالى وجهه قال: قال لي رسول اللّه
>   صلّى اللّه عليه و سلم: «ألم تسمع قول اللّه تعالى إِنَّ الَّذِينَ
>   آمَنُوا وَ عَمِلُوا الصَّالِحاتِ أُولئِكَ هُمْ خَيْرُ الْبَرِيَّةِ؟ هم
>   أنت و شيعتك و موعدي و موعدكم الحوض إذا جثت الأمم للحساب يدعون غرا
>   محجلين» و روى نحوه الإمامية عن يزيد بن شراحيل الأنصاري كاتب الأمير كرم
>   اللّه تعالى وجهه. و فيه أنه عليه الصلاة و السلام قال ذلك له عند الوفاة
>   و رأسه الشريف على صدره رضي اللّه تعالى عنه. و
>
> أخرج ابن مردويه أيضا عن ابن عباس قال: لما نزلت هذه الآية إِنَّ
>   الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا إلخ قال رسول اللّه صلّى اللّه عليه و سلم لعلي رضي
>   اللّه تعالى عنه و كرم وجهه: «هو أنت و شيعتك يوم القيامة راضين مرضيين
>
> سید محمد آلوسى (قرن ۱۳)، روح المعاني في تفسير القرآن العظيم، ج15، ص:
>   432

AbdulHaq ibn Qalib ibn Attiyeh Andelusy (the 6th Hijri century) has written in his book that the holy Prophet --peace be upon him-- told Imam Ali --peace be upon him-- that you and your followers (Shia) are the best of creatures

> و روي حديث عن النبي صلى اللّه عليه و سلم أنه قرأ هذه الآية: «أولئك هم
>   خير البريئة». ثم قال لعلي بن أبي طالب رضي اللّه عنه «أنت يا علي و
>   شيعتك من خير البرية»، ذكره الطبري.
>
> عبدالحق بن غالب ابن عطيه اندلسى، المحرر الوجيز في تفسير الكتاب العزيز،
>   ج5، ص: 508

And the Sunnism were originated a few hours or days after the holy Prophet --peace be upon him-- passed away and indeed the Sunni brothers claim the holy prophet --peace be upon him and his household-- had not introduced who should be his successor after him as Caliph, so that Sunnism as a political sect could not be started at the time of the holy Prophet --peace be upon him and his household.

Comment: Oh, @owari, your answer doesn't deserve -1, since you strived to elaborate it by several hadiths from Sunni books which seems to be authentic from the viewpoint of dear Sunni brothers. Otherwise your response looks nice, on the whole.

Answer (score 0):

```
                            بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم
```

Briefly speaking, there can be several constructive points concerning the division of Shia and Sunni:

- Shi’a means followers (Shi’a follows the direction which chose by the
  Prophet (and actually by Allah) since Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) chose
  Imam Ali as his successor…). In fact, after Allah as the God, they
  follow the Prophet and then the direction as he showed and appointed
  Imam Ali... (Not solely they follow Imam Ali)
- Generally, the word “Shia’ is available in the Quran, E.g. وَإِنَّ
  مِن شِيعَتِهِ لَإِبْرَاهِيمَ and some other verses, but there isn’t
  the word “Sunni”…, then it shows that being the follower of the right
  sect or direction would be right.

---

Moreover, Battle of Karbala also mentioned correctly that according to Shia only God can select the Caliph and God selected his Caliph after prophet and he was Ali S.A. and Ali S.A. received divine knowledge of prophet to guide humans and …

> And prophet declared it in front of 120,000 Muslims at Ghadir at final
>   Hajj of prophet and Abubakr and Umar and Uthman given Bayat (pledge of
>   alliance) to Ali S.A. but when prophet died and Ali S.A. was at
>   funeral of prophet they left the funeral and made a meeting at Saqifah
>   Bani Saedeh and selected Abubakr as Caliph without any permission from
>   God and prophet and cause misguide of all humanity.

---

Or even the explanation of the Bludream would be helpful a lot that he mentioned Hajjatul-Wada' حجه الوداع as the main origin of Shia that when the Prophet (sa)  visited Mecca for the last time and many people accompanied him, on the way back near غدیرخم Ghadir pond, he(sa) ordered everyone to stay and sent for others in front to return and waited for those behind to come up and after some thousand people were gathered He ordered to make a platform like place with camel saddles and then he went up with Imam Ali (as) and took up his hand and told people that

> Whoever I am his Mola مولا from now on Ali is his Mola.

Then he told them to spread the word and tell everyone. As a result, how can we deny such an important matter by some excuse…?! (I can explain about the excuse which dear Sunni brothers say about it…) Hence Shias believe that Prophet (sa) clearly appointed Ali (as) as his successor.

---

**Conclusion:**

Totally, Shia was available from the first and actually they were followers of the Prophet (pbuh) and also Imam Ali (a.s.) (as the Prophet appointed him as his successor), but seemingly they divided from Sunni since “at Ghadir at final Hajj of prophet (s)” and dear Sunni brothers chose the other ways. (That: … when prophet died and Ali S.A. was at funeral of prophet, they left the funeral and made a meeting at Saqifah Bani Saedeh and selected Abubakr as Caliph without any permission from God and prophet…). Hence it can be named as the origins of Shia and Sunni division.

---

**References**:

- [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#37:83)
- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa7505)