# What does the word "Shia" mean?

Tags: shia-sunni

As-salaamu 'alaykum, wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh.

I am aware that the word "Sunnah" means "way of", or "teaching". Therefore, a Muslim who is a Sunni is one who, at least technically, follows the prescribed ways and teachings of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him).

Does the word "Shia" also have a meaning?

Comment: I think this post is helpful if you are looking for the meaning only http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/967/what-are-the-origins-of-shia-and-sunni-division