# Do Shia and Sunni have different Qurans?

Tags: quran, shia-sunni

I recently heard that Shia and Sunni have different Qurans. Is that true? If so, why do they have different Qurans (that is different physical copies)?

Comment: **not different**, even if different, it just about the order of surah in quran..

Comment: Yeah. of course AFAIK, they are the same even in the order of arrangement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is **not** true, the Quran is the same and this is the opinion of most of Shia scholars.

The small kid who memorizes the Quran in Iran (i.e. Shia) will recite the same thing as another one who memorized the Quran in a Sunni country.

The major difference between Sunnah and Shia in terms of the sources are related to Sunnah or the Prophet -peace upon him- (i.e. the Sunnah).

For example, Shia does not accept the trusted hadith books of Sunnah as Al-Bukhari.

Comment: @NeilMeyer, [Wikipedia: differences in beliefs and practices between Sunni and Shia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shia%E2%80%93Sunni_relations#Differences_in_beliefs_and_practices).

Comment: @NeilMeyer, you may also want to check [my answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/964/42) to [Why does Shi'a Islam differ so much regarding Abu Bakr, Omar and Othman, compared to Sunni teachings?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/961/42)